# Domain in read_group method

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

There is standard method

```
 def read_group(self, cr, uid, domain, fields, groupby, offset=0, limit=None, context=None, orderby=False)
```

I'm calling a super on it and passing a domain like this

```
[('end_date', '>=', '2019-05-01'), ('end_date', '<=', '2019-05-30'), ('employee', 'in', [49]), ('state', 'in', ['done'])]
```

and it works.

but when I try to append

```
domain.append(('&'))
domain.append(('state', 'in', ['progress']))
```

I get

```
File "/home/www/workspace/openerp-7.0-20140804-231303/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 201, in normalize_domain
    assert expected == 0, 'This domain is syntactically not correct: %s' % (domain)
AssertionError: This domain is syntactically not correct: [('end_date', '>=', '2019-05-01'), ('end_date', '<=', '2019-05-30'), ('employee', 'in', [49]), ('state', 'in', ['done']), '&', ('state', 'in', ['progress'])]
```

basically, need to filter all records by dates and in state '`done'`  and on top of that all records in state 'progress'.

**UPDATE.**

if I user domain

```
domain = [('end_date', '>=', '2019-05-01'), ('end_date', '<=', '2019-05-30'), ('employee', 'in', [49]),
         ('state', 'in', ['done'])]
```

i get 3 records,

and if I use

```
domain = [('employee', 'in', [49]), ('state', 'in', ['progress'])]
```

I get result with 2 records,

but if I combine these domains like this I get 0 records

```
domain = [('state', 'in', ['progress']),('end_date', '>=', '2019-05-01'), ('end_date', '<=', '2019-05-30'), ('employee', 'in', [49]),
         ('state', 'in', ['done'])]
```

how my domain should look that i would get 5 records?

probably problem is that records that in `'progress'` doesnt have `end_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical operators '&' and '|' have arity 2, that means 2 triples ("normal" domain tuples with 3 entries) must follow them. You append only one triple. In your case you can just remove the `append` of '&' because without using any logical operator, everything/every triple will be combined with AND per default.

The logical operator '!' has arity 1, btw.

You can find enough information about it in [the official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#domains).

> A domain is a list of criteria, each criterion being a triple (either
>   a list or a tuple) of (field_name, operator, value) where:
>
> field_name (str) a field name of the current model, or a relationship
>   traversal through a Many2one using dot-notation e.g. 'street' or
>   'partner_id.country' operator (str) an operator used to compare the
>   field_name with the value. Valid operators are:
>
> = equals to != not equals to
>
> > greater than
>
> >= greater than or equal to
>
> < less than
>
> <= less than or equal to
>
> =? unset or equals to (returns true if value is either None or False, otherwise behaves like =)
>
> =like matches field_name against the value pattern. An underscore _ in the pattern stands for (matches) any single character; a percent sign % matches any string of zero or more characters.
>
> like matches field_name against the %value% pattern. Similar to =like but wraps value with ‘%’ before matching
>
> not like doesn’t match against the %value% pattern
>
> ilike case insensitive like
>
> not ilike case insensitive not like
>
> =ilike case insensitive =like
>
> in is equal to any of the items from value, value should be a list of items
>
> not in is unequal to all of the items from value
>
> child_of is a child (descendant) of a value record. Takes the semantics of the model into account (i.e following the relationship field named by _parent_name).
>
> Domain criteria can be combined using logical operators in prefix form:
>
> '&' logical AND, default operation to combine criteria following one
>   another. Arity 2 (uses the next 2 criteria or combinations).
>
> '|' logical OR, arity 2.
>
> '!' logical NOT, arity 1.

Edit: Even if it should be another question, i'll try to solve your special domain problem:

```
[('employee_id', 'in', [49]),
'|',
    ('state', 'in', ['progress']),
    '&', ('state', 'in', ['done']),
        '&', ('end_date', '>=', '2019-05-01'), ('end_date', '<=', '2019-05-30')]
```

That should outcome as (pseudo):

```
EMPLOYEE with ID 49 AND
(STATE is progress OR (STATE is done AND END_DATE is between ...))
```

Comment: maybe you can check my question again? I updated. still can't figure out how to group my domains

Comment: i've edited my answer. But you should stop editing in other questions. For you it may be the same problem, but now there are two questions only related a little bit to eachother.

Comment: Ok , sorry for misunderstanding  and thank you for update